# ZF2 Module (Application) could not be initialized

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I have application.config.php which is 100% right:

```
return array(
    'modules' => array(
        'Application',
    ),
    'module_listener_options' => array(
        'config_glob_paths'    => array(
            'config/autoload/{,*.}{local,global}.php',
        ),
        'config_cache_enabled' => false,
        'cache_dir' => 'data/cache',
        'module_paths' => array(
            realpath(__DIR__ . '/../module'),
        ),
    )
);
```

Then I get this error:

> Module (Application) could not be initialized.

I have followed the error and it seem that ModuleAutoloader isn't loading my files.

The `$this->paths` array is right to the module folder. My Module file is in `module/Application/Module.php`

It is a namespaced application and the class is Module. I just can't get what the problem might be.

```
<?php
namespace Application;

class Module
{
    /**
     * Module directory path
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $directory = null;

    /**
     * Module namespace
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $namespace = null;

    /**
     * Module configuration
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $config;

    /**
     * Get autoloader config
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getAutoloaderConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'Zend\Loader\ClassMapAutoloader' => array(
                $this->getDir() . '/autoload_classmap.php',
            ),
            'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
                'namespaces' => array(
                    $this->getNamespace() => $this->getDir() . '/src/' . $this->getNamespace(),
                ),
            ),
        );
    }

    /**
     * Get module configuration
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getConfig()
    {
        if (empty($this->config)) {
            $config       = include $this->getDir() . '/config/module.config.php';
            $this->config = $config;
        }

        return $this->config;
    }

    /**
     * Get module dir
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function getDir()
    {
        return $this->directory;
    }

    /**
     * get module namespace
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function getNamespace()
    {
        return $this->namespace;
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you please show us the Module.php

Comment: i added the Module.php

Comment: Is the $this->directory empty?

Comment: The class Module isnt loaded so i cant tell

Comment: Check your module folder permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Try using magic constants instead of the functions for the namespaces and dirs, like this

```
public function getAutoloaderConfig() {
    return array (
            'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array (
                    'namespaces' => array (
                            __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__ 
                    ) 
            ) 
    );
}
```

And in your application.config.php, you can simplify it this way:

```
'module_paths' => array(
        './module', 
    ),
```

if this does not work, you can try to hard code the full module path to see if there is something wrong with the autoloader:

```
'module_paths' => array(
    './module',            
    'Application' => './module/Application/src/Application' 
),
```

Comment: Nothing happens, the class Module.php still isnt loaded. When i echo something in the ModuleLoader -> autoloader function there is no result. But the register is called. I just cant figure it out

Comment: im not sure if you are using the proper autoloader. could you post your init_autoloader.php contents?

Comment: it is not changed from the original skeleton application. If you search the logic you see that when the ::init calls the ModuleManager to ->loadModules there is an event listener which is ModuleLoaderListener. In this event is the ModuleAutloader that loads all Module.php files

Comment: i asked because im not sure if you are in zf2, or in 2.2, and also what version of the skeletonapplication you have, since you should be wondering about the composer autoloader or the Zend\Loader\AutoloaderFactory rather than the ModuleAtoloader. Do you have the last versions of the framework and the skeleton app? there is some slight changes in the autoloading and im not sure if i can figure out what is happening if we use diferent versions

Comment: Yes i downloaded the last zf version 2.2.5 and this is my index.php file
/**
  * Display all errors when APPLICATION_ENV is development.
  */
 if ($_SERVER['APPLICATION_ENV'] == 'development') {
     error_reporting(E_ALL);
     ini_set("display_errors", 1);
 }

 /**
  * This makes our life easier when dealing with paths. Everything is relative
  * to the application root now.
  */
 chdir(dirname(__DIR__));

 // Setup autoloading
 require 'init_autoloader.php';

 // Run the application!
 Zend\Mvc\Application::init(require 'config/application.config.php')->run();

Comment: the version is great. and the skeleton is also the last, is your init_autoloader.php  this one? https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/blob/master/init_autoloader.php

Comment: i dont know if it is an error in the copy paste, but  `chdir(dirname(DIR));` should be  `chdir(dirname(__DIR__));`

Comment: yes this is init_autoloader and sorry my mistake with copy / paste the dir is right

Comment: when i echo in ModuleAutoloader here
public function autoload($class)
    { echo $class;
        // Limit scope of this autoloader
        if (substr($class, -7) !== '\Module') {
            return false;
        }

i get nothing. So there is something wrong with this autloader and this problem is killing me .

Comment: i think you should be using composer autoloader. do you have 'vendor/autoload.php'? can you follow the includes and function calls to see if everything is working as expected?

Comment: i dont have any vendor/autoloader. And as far as i know everything is perfect until this ModuleAutoloader which for some reason doesnt include my classes. I tried even to set_paths for it, but no result. I dont know how to use this composer autoloader, but i will search for it

Comment: Lately most people is using composer, so it is not wasting time if you take a moment to learn about it. Anyways if you can wait, I can give you some advice, but I wont have a computer until 3 hours from now

Comment: if you dowonlad the app from here https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/tarball/master, it is already ready for composer. As you can read here http://framework.zend.com/downloads/skeleton-app, composer is what zend recommends. just unzip de file. open a command promopt, make sure that php executable is in your path, and just run `php composer.phar install`

Answer (score 0):

Change 'module_paths' to:

```
'module_paths' => array(
    '../../module',
    '../../vendor',
)
```